# New byte in php

Tags: java, php, byte

I have code JAVA

```
byte abyte1[] = new byte[k];
```

But php not have byte type. Its possible to convert this line to php?

Comment: you don't need to convert line by line. How is this byte array used?

Answer (score 7):

The concept of a fixed-length array is not really one that exists in php. Additonally, you don't specify the type of an array either, instead all arrays are actually a hash, that can store any type.

The closest thing to what you ask is:

```
$abyte1 = array();
```

And then you can just insert bytes as you might normally:

```
$abyte1[0] = 1;
$abyte1[1] = 2;
```

Or you can add to the end of the list:

```
$abyte1[] = 3;
```

Comment: As of PHP5.3, PHP does have Fixed Length Arrays through SplFixedArray http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php

Comment: @Gordon, duly noted, however the comments at the bottom of the page suggest only marginal performance gains for small sets of data.  Additionally, as you said, it is only in 5.3.